# Probability interval of normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

> Consider a random sample of 25 observations which follow a normal
>   distribution N(0,1). Which of the following is an approximate 95%
>   probability interval for the sample proportion of observations larger
>   than 1?
>
> (0.06, 0.60)
>
> (0.01, 0.15)
>
> (0.03, 0.20)
>
> (0.02, 0.30)
>
> (0.15, 0.60)

I know that I have to find the probability of success which is binomial and then use the distribution of p-hat to find the 95% Probability interval. I'm just having problems on finding the probability of success (P(X>1))

would really appreciate your help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

We must first find the probability that an individual observation is larger than one. Letting $X\sim \mathsf N(0,1)$ we get

$$P(X\gt1)=1-P(X<1)=1-\Phi\left(1\right)\approx0.1587$$

```
> 1-pnorm(1)
[1] 0.1586553
```

A $95$% confidence interval for $p$, the sample proportion, is given by

$$p_0\pm 1.96\cdot\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}$$

where $p_0\approx0.1587$ and $n=25$